# how to export sql data to csv using bcp

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

I use simple code

```
declare @sql varchar(8000) 
select @sql  = 'bcp ExcelAnalysis.dbo.ClearDB out c:\csv\comm.txt -c -t, -T -S '+ @@servername 
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

but this code export all my table, but i need only some fields and conditions
like:

```
declare @sql varchar(8000) 
select @sql = 'bcp 
SELECT 

      ,[vl]
      ,[data]
      ,[URL]
      ,[parse]
      ,[Strata]
      ,[Id]
   FROM [ExcelAnalysis].[dbo].[ClearDB] where [data]> "01.05.2017" and NOT [vl] ="mag"and NOT [vl] ="Maxximo"   out c:\csv\status.txt -c -t, -T -S '+ @@servername 
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

but if i use any fields, the bcd returns message with his syntax.
How do correct?

Comment: Create the query in a view and use that as DB object

Comment: could you show me? i don't know. i'm newby

Answer (score 10):

First Part : Create  a view in database and second part to execute statement to get results into CSV.Let me know if you need more help

```
use [ExcelAnalysis].
go
;

create view [dbo].[vw_ClearDB] as
SELECT 

      [vl]
      ,[data]
      ,[URL]
      ,[parse]
      ,[Strata]
      ,[Id]
   FROM [dbo].[ClearDB] where [data]> "01.05.2017" and NOT [vl] ='magand'
   NOT [vl] ='Maxximo'

   GO

   ;


declare @sql varchar(8000) 
select @sql  = 'bcp ExcelAnalysis.dbo.vw_ClearDB out c:\csv\comm.txt -c -t, -T -S '+ @@servername 
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Comment: could you tell, i did like you, but error  'Message 102, level 15, state 1, procedure vw_ClearDB, line 29
Wrong syntax near the "GO" structure.'

Comment: Enter the query directly as the first BCP parameter and `queryoutfor the second.

Comment: For the view method, enclose string literals in single-quotes instead of double-quotes.

Comment: I got it. The semicolon must be before GO,  after the query. Thnx.)

Comment: Hope its solved @D.Joe. Sorry have only seen your message now, Intellisense onthe server  should solve itself

Answer (score 6):

[Bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) **queryout** option should be used.

Syntax would be:

```
SET @sql = 'bcp "SELECT [vl]
            ,[data]
            ,[URL]
            ,[parse]
            ,[Strata]
            ,[Id]
        FROM [dbo].[ClearDB] 
        WHERE [data] > ''01.05.2017''
        AND NOT [vl] =''mag''
        AND NOT [vl] =''Maxximo''" 
    queryout c:\csv\comm.txt
    -c -t, -T -S '+ @@servername + '\' + @@servicename
```