# BCP in sql server with select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

i want to take the data from select query to txt or csv formate with comma separated in sql server 2008

Comment: @YogeshSharma
 
SET bcpCommand = 'bcp "select * from table_name" queryout '
SET FilePath = 'C:\file\bcp\'
SET OutputFile = 'new.txt'
SET bcpCommand = bcpCommand + FilePath + OutputFile + ' -S servername -U username -P password'
exec master..xp_cmdshell bcpCommand

Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file

at the rate im missing because of it is considering as user...

Comment: Use this post , explains BCP command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606889/how-to-export-sql-data-to-csv-using-bcp/44607037#44607037

Answer (score 0):

You Can use SSIS if this is going to be a scheduled or repeating requirement. But If this is just a one-time requirement then probably the Import Export Wizard that comes along the SSMS will be enough.

Check The Below Links :

[Using SSIS](http://knowlton-group.com/using-ssis-to-export-data-to-flat-files/)

[Using Import Export Wizard](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-export-sql-server-data-to-a-csv-file/)